# aws devicefarm Remote debugging sessions

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-device-farm

I try to use aws device farm tool. I have IAMuser account. I login AWS Device Farm application with my user which has devicefarm permission. But ı cant see devices on tool.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdYbI.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AWS Device Farm app doesn't list any devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51069564/aws-device-farm-app-doesnt-list-any-devices)

Answer (score 0):

That desktop app is for private devices in device farm.  For remote access sessions in the public offering we will need to use the web console.