# AWS Device Farm app doesn't list any devices

Tags: android, android-studio, aws-device-farm

I'm attempting to manually test and debug apps from Android Studio in my AWS WorkSpace using AWS Device Farm. I downloaded the Device Farm app, and followed all of the instructions, but no devices are showing up in the list when I'm trying to create a new remote debugging session. My workspace is in us-east-1 and the device farm is in us-west-2, but I don't think that matters since I got the same behavior from my laptop. Any ideas I can try out?

Comment: You're probably using the desktop app. That is for private devices only. So if you don't have any private devices in your account nothing will be shown. 

You'll need to use the web console to schedule a run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the Device Farm app is for Direct Device Access(DDA) which is only available to private devices.

You can find more information about private device at this link: https://aws.amazon.com/device-farm/pricing/#privateDevices

Comment: That explains that. Thanks!